# How to Group and sort IEnumerable in in one line in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a List which needs to be grouped on 2 columns of it. After that how can we order the result based on just one column which is part of 2 columns on basis of which List has been grouped.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, T>> groupBy = items.GroupBy(x => groupOn(x))
```

groupOn is Func which returns column names on basis of which list is grouped. Suppose list is Grouped on basis of Column A and Column B, now since result obtained is of type
    IGrouping How can I sort groupBy on basis of Column A. Thanks in advance.

```
public static ObservableCollection<O> exampleMethod<T, O>(IList<T> items, Func<T, object> groupOn)
{
 IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, T>> groupBy = items.GroupBy(x => groupOn(x)); 
}
var plans = exampleMethod<ExampleCollection, ExampleClass>(newExampleCollection, o => new { o.A, o.B})
```

Comment: Which you you wanna sort?

Comment: @CoungLe I want to sort IEnumerable groupBy

Comment: be honest, your question is not clear to answer, you need to elaborate more your expectation clearly.

Comment: @CoungLe can we discuss it on the chat window for this question?